# What is happening to my HDRI?

Tags: hdri

I have been trying all the troubleshooting that was to find in here and on google. Can somebody please explain to me what settings that is wrong since my world map is showing up HUGE in the background and seemslike on the reflection of the can aswell. Please help!

[image]

best regards
Anders

Comment: Thank you so much sir! Was exactly the same problem I encountered :)